# Facebook API: is a time interval between calls needed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need my app to continuously call the Facebook API.
Should I set an interval between each call or just make sure it doesn't make more calls than what the developers declared a single app can do and catch warning about too many calls?

If so, what would be a good interval amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we need to set any interval between consecutive calls to `Facebook API`, I make many consecutive calls at a time, it does not cause any problem. If you are going to make too many calls then you will just need to keep throttle limits in mind.